# Why is ReSharper telling me that the local variable is unused and that I'm accessing a modified closure?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, resharper

I have the following code:

```
dataContext.Objects.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dataContext.Objects.Where(o => o.Id == object.Id));
```

ReSharper is underlining `object.Id` and telling me:

> Access to modified closure

I understand why it's doing this and have changed the code to:

```
int localId = object.Id; 
dataContext.Objects.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dataContext.Objects.Where(o => o.Id == localId));
```

But now ReSharper is giving me **two** underlines. The first is under `localId` where it's declared and assigned:

> Value assigned is not used in any execution path

and the second is under `localId` where it's used in the query and is still:

> Access to modified closure

Why is this happening? Is the local variable being optimised out so that I'm still effectively accessing the object's field in the query?

Is this something I need to worry about? The code appears to be working correctly, but I'm trying to ensure that we've not left any time-bombs lying around.

Is there anything I can do (other than just ignoring these messages) to solve the problem?

Splitting the code like this and realising the query:

```
int localId = object.Id;
var objectsToDelete = dataContext.Objects.Where(o => o.Id == localId)).ToList();
dataContext.Objects.DeleteAllOnSubmit(objectsToDelete);
```

solves the "Access to modified closure" message, but leaves the "Value assigned is not used in any execution path" message. That's only solved by removing it altogether:

```
var objectsToDelete = dataContext.Objects.Where(o => o.Id == object.Id)).ToList();
dataContext.Objects.DeleteAllOnSubmit(objectsToDelete);
```